# Hosting Back end Application with API on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, symfony, amazon-ec2

I'm quite new to AWS and I have been starting to work with EC2 instances. I have a web application that has a frontend and backend separately. So first I hosted the backend application on EC2 instance and it is a Symfony framework based REST API Application. So I have installed all dependencies and now the application is running. But to check the application I ran some API calls to the application using postman and seems application is not working as intended. I get following response from Postman. I have also provided security group configurations properly.
When I start sysmfony app it says [OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000.

Can't figure out why this is happening. Can someone help me here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: try without port `8000`

Comment: Then it goes to apache home page @ImanaliMamadiev

Comment: Are you running your symfony application using cli command?

Comment: Yes, I started the application by running, php bin/console server:start

Answer (score 1):

You are running your application trough CLI (Symfony web server bundle) , by default this will bind to `127.0.0.1` which can't be accessed from outside. To fix this, you must bind to your server's public IP/hostname and port:

```
php bin/console server:start 192.168.1.1:8000 # replace with your ip
```

You can also bind to all your IP addresses using `0.0.0.0`

But keep in mind, you should not use built in server for production, it's slow and less secure. Use a real web server instead, like Apache or Nginx.

Comment: I have installed apache, so what should I do then?